# greek character set in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with greek characters in oracle 11g. It onlys shows some greek characters and all the others with '?'. I have done all the things above, that I found in internet but can't fix this.

I use win vista (rus/eng version) and set up the greek mui. I've changed NLS_LANG in registry to EL8MSWIN1253 (i've changed that), my system nls_lang is 1253 in registry too.

When i call:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_INSTANSE_PARAMETERS
```

I get `NLS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN` and `NLS_TERRITORY=AMERICA`. I set up oracle with Unicode character set.

I tried to call

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANG=GREEK_GREECE.EL8MSWIN1253
```

but that didn't work. When i call

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=GREEK
```

or

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=GREECE
```

Oracle says "Session altered" but nothing changes.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows: Don’t mess up fonts being used in Command Shell / Command prompt (under Windows) with Windows fonts (e.g. fonts being used in Windows applications, such in SQL Developer).
If you wish to display Greek characters correctly under SQL*Plus in Command prompt:

Identify the active Code Page:

```
C:\> chcp
```

The system should respond with the code page number. This for Greek language should be:

> Active code page: 737

The 737 corresponds to the
EL8PC737 Oracle Client character set (3rd part of NLS_LANG). See at:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html#_Toc110410555

Set the Oracle NLS environment variable:

```
C:\> set NLS_LANG= GREEK_GREECE.EL8PC737
```

Now logging in SQL*Plus you will be able to see Greek characters correctly in query results.

Make analogous settings for any other national language.

Panos Zafiropoulos

Answer (score 0):

Did you set NLS_LANG in the registry to `.EL8MSWIN1253` (notice the prefix dot)?

The format of NLS_LANG is this:

```
NLS_LANG = language_territory.charset
```

...and the [Oracle® Database Globalization Support Guide manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298.pdf) writes:

> All components of the NLS_LANG
>   definition are optional; any item that
>   is not specified uses its default
>   value. *If you specify territory or
>   character set, then you must include
>   the preceding delimiter* [underscore
>   (_) for territory, **period (.) for
>   character set**]. Otherwise, the value
>   is parsed as a language name.

Comment: You mean I should write .EL8MSWIN1253 in NLS_LANG? I haven't done this. I 'll sheck this. Thanks Anders

Comment: I checked this and I'm writing : GREEK_GREECE.EL8MSWIN1253, isn't this correct?

Comment: I think that is the correct value to put in the registry, yes.

Comment: Hard to tell without any clues, could you update your question with what happens?

Comment: Have the same issue here! When I query my db with greek characters I get ??? as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out that character set conversion occurs BOTH ways. So if a client inserts a 'greek' character when their database session indicates an american character set, then the character will be converted from **American** to UTF-8 (or whatever the DB character set is). A subsequent select by a session with a greek character set will result in the translation of the character from UTF-8 to greek, which might not be what you started with.

Use `select DUMP(col)` to see they bytes recorded in the database, then you can work out whether the database has the correct representation of the character.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on my computer > Advance system setting > advance > Environment Variables

Click on System variable on New TAB

Variable name : NLS_LANG
Variable Value : GREEK_GREECE.EL8MSWIN1253

Variable name : NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS
Variable Value : .,